# SimpleIoc missing from MVVM Light Nuget package

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light, nuget

I'm unable to find the SimpleIoc type within the Nuget MVVM Light assemblies for WP71 has it been removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of MVVMLight did you install?

From what I understand, `SimpleIoc` is only available in the MVVMLight 4 preview package. It wasn't included in MVVMLight 3.

I verified that it's available in the MVVMLight Preview by installing the package in a demo project and opening the .dlls in ILSpy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better place to ask would be on the project's site:

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

*EDIT

It seems like the NuGet package you installed was for V3.

Check this post: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2011/12/18/mvvm-light-installers-and-nuget-including-silverlight-5-mvvmlight.aspx

You should probably install "MVVM Light [Preview]" if it becomes available, but I do not see it now.

For now I think you will need to do without NuGet and just install it manually or get the sources.

Here is the link to get the installer:
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/73208

Comment: Well, actually ... :) Laurent Bugnion, the creator of MVVM Light, has encouraged users to post questions here for faster answers.

Comment: He did, huh? :)
Well, I guess he has an alert for the mvvm-light tag. :)